# Integrals of the Fresnel integrals

Tags: fresnel-integrals

I find in an engineering book the Integrals of the Fresnel integrals and i don't know how to prove the expressions given bellow.

$$C_I(t)=\int_{0}^{1}C(u)du=tC(t)-\frac{1}{\pi}sin(\frac{\pi t^2}{2})$$
and
$$S_I(t)=\int_{0}^{1}S(u)du=tS(t)+\frac{1}{\pi}cos(\frac{\pi t^2}{2})-\frac{1}{\pi}$$

Where the Fresnel integrals are:
$$C(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\cos(\frac{\pi u^2}{2})du$$
$$S(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\sin(\frac{\pi u^2}{2})du$$

I tried to solve the integrals as they are but i know they are a special type of integrals and i don't know how to start properly the proof. Thank you !

Comment: There is something strange here. Your integrals are definite integrals between $0$ and $1$, so they must be numbers. What is $t$ in $C_I(t)$?

Comment: Integration by parts seems like a reasonable approach. I think you meant the upper limit to be $t$, not $1$?

Comment: Well, the only information that book provides about this t is that, t are a parameter that is used in the parametric equations of the clothoid or euler spiral .

Comment: Or are they integrals from $0$ to $t$ instead?

Comment: I know that all papers about Fresnel integrals say that are improper integrals but in this book they appear with 0,t limits

Comment: You can consider the integrals from $0$ to $t$, and then $C(t)$ and $S(t)$ give a parametrization of the Euler spiral.

Comment: The upper limits must be typos. See [integral of $C$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+FresnelC%28u%29+from+u%3D0+to+t) and [integral of $S$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+FresnelC%28u%29+from+u%3D0+to+t) from $0$ to $t$.